# Split string after certain sequence. E.g Text/0000/text/text

Tags: javascript

I need to split string/ or get substring whichever is easier from string that will have following structure.

String will come from either `window.location.pathname` or `window.location.href` which looks like `text/numbers/text/text`

e.g `google.com/first/page/0000-1234/another/page`

So desired result should be: `anotherpage`

I want to concatenate anything after the numbers and remove the /.

Edited as requirement changed. Number has a dash in between

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the string without '/' then try below one:

```
let str = 'google.com/first/page/12345678/another/page';
let outputResult = str.split('/').join('');
output will be: --> 'google.comfirstpage12345678anotherpage'
```

For perticular case i.e. 'anotherpage' you can try below:

```
let str = 'google.com/first/page/12345678/another/page';
let op = str.split('/');
let result = op.splice(op.length - 2).join('');

result ==> 'anotherpage'
```

Comment: I support this answere because it uses simple string search and not the "costly" regex engine for simple string parsing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, this can do the trick.

```js
const pathname = window.location.pathname
const regex = /\/(\d*)\//g
const whatYouNeed = pathname
  .split(regex)
  .pop()
  .replace(/\//g, '')

console.log(whatYouNeed)
```

Comment: It worked, but then I realised, there is a dash between the numbers and it doesn't work for that. so numbers will be like /0000-1234/ Do you know what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get the path name after the number:

```js
const regex = /\/\d*\/(.*)/;
const str = 'google.com/first/page/12345678/another/page';

const [, pathname] = str.match(regex);

const result = pathname.split('/').join('')

console.log({ result })
```